# pm2 não é reconhecido

Tags: node.js

Após dar o comando

```
npm i -g pm2
```

Ao fechar e abrir o cmd e digitar pm2 para testar

Ele diz que:

> 'pm2' não é reconhecido como um comando interno ou externo, um
>   programa operável ou um arquivo em lotes

Como fazer para o pm2 ser reconhecido?

O node instalado é 10.12.0

Comment: Tentou fechar e abrir o terminal novamente? Reiniciou a máquina e tentou instalar novamente? Nem com sudo funciona né? Sobre a versão do node, embora acredito que não interfira, existe um motivo para estar em uma versão mais antiga? Caso não tiver, talvez seja interessante também sempre manter em uma das últimas versões.

Comment: Fechei e abri o terminal, reinicei o servidor, sem como adm funcionou. Na verdade, estava na versão 10, porque foi à época em que eu instalei. Fucionou só depois que eu adicionar o caminho do node_modules\,bin  no path

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O que eu tentei:

- Fechei e abri
- Reinicei o servidor
- Tentei como administrador

Nada disso funcionou:

Percebi que tinha uma pasta node_modules na minha unidade onde ficam as apis

```
C\node-pm2\node_modules
```

Dentro dessa pasta tem a pasta .bin\pm2

Se eu rodar o comando pm2 dentro dela o pm2 funciona. Então copiei o endereço acima `C\node-pm2\node_modules` e adiconei no PATH das variáveis de ambiente e funcionou

Agora não entendi o porquê de usando o comando `npm i -g pm2` não funcionou